# CentOs 7 - Java SQL error

Tags: java, mysql, centos

I've got a SQL link error which is weird because from my local pc it works perfect and both try to connect to the same external Database. Both IP's are allowed in my external DB server.

I am making a bukkit plugin which tries to connect using the java SQL library and: https://github.com/Huskehhh/MySQL

And the error:

```
[12:43:48 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[12:43:48 WARN]:at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:983)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2252)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2285)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.huskehhh.mysql.mysql.MySQL.openConnection(MySQL.java:76)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at me.spigot.UGxSynteX.islands.Island.onEnable(Island.java:50)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:292)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:362)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:322)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:412)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:377)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:332)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:271)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:535)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12:43:48 WARN]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214)
[12:43:48 WARN]:at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
[12:43:48 WARN]:... 27 more
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai) post.This might help you out.

Comment: @zombie Thank you i already checked that out i can ping from that server to the database server but i think this server doesn;t have a SQL driver is that possible? if so how do i install that on centos7

Answer (score 0):

Somehow CSF blocked it from my other VPS but not from my PC. Both ip's weren't allowed but he blocked my other VPS after adding it to the whitlist everything is allright